# real word count in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

The NLTK book has a couple of examples of word counts, but in reality they are not word counts but token counts. For instance, Chapter 1, Counting Vocabulary says that the following gives a word count:

```
text = nltk.Text(tokens)
len(text)
```

However, it doesn't - it gives a word and punctuation count.
How can you get a real word count (ignoring punctuation)?

Similarly, how can you get the average number of characters in a word? 
The obvious answer is:

```
word_average_length =(len(string_of_text)/len(text))
```

However, this would be off because:

1. len(string_of_text) is a character count, including spaces
2. len(text) is a token count, excluding spaces but including punctuation marks, which aren't words.

Am I missing something here? This must be a very common NLP task...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Removing Punctuation

Use a regular expression to filter out the punctuation

```
import re
from collections import Counter

>>> text = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.']
>>> nonPunct = re.compile('.*[A-Za-z0-9].*')  # must contain a letter or digit
>>> filtered = [w for w in text if nonPunct.match(w)]
>>> counts = Counter(filtered)
>>> counts
Counter({'this': 1, 'a': 1, 'is': 1, 'sentence': 1})
```

### Average Number of Characters

Sum the lengths of each word.  Divide by the number of words.

```
>>> float(sum(map(len, filtered))) / len(filtered)
3.75
```

Or you could make use of the counts you already did to prevent some re-computation.  This multiplies the length of the word by the number of times we saw it, then sums all of that up.

```
>>> float(sum(len(w)*c for w,c in counts.iteritems())) / len(filtered)
3.75
```

Comment: So the NLTK does't have any functions for these operations?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `re.split()` on punctuation and whitespace.

Comment: @Joel: That would cause problems for punctuation that is embedded inside of words (eg, `U.S.`).

Comment: @dhg: `U.S.` pretty ambiguous, but I see what you're saying. Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're not using `re.findall()` ?

Comment: @Joel: 1) I mean't that if you split the word `U.S.` on punctuation, you would get the two words `U` and `S`, and that is wrong.  2) `findall` would work in this particular case, but the way I've written it, you can use the regex to define exactly what it means to be a "punctuation token" (perhaps in a more complex way than I have).

Answer (score 23):

Tokenization with nltk

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
text = "This is my text. It icludes commas, question marks? and other stuff. Also U.S.."
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

Returns

```
['This', 'is', 'my', 'text', 'It', 'icludes', 'commas', 'question', 'marks', 'and', 'other', 'stuff', 'Also', 'U', 'S']
```

Comment: hey, keep in mind that nltk counts "it's" as two word. Try with 
text = "Hi, it's me". Output is ['Hi', 'it', 's', 'me']

Answer (score 2):

### Removing Punctuation (with no regex)

Use the same solution as [dhg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247985/dhg), but test that a given token is alphanumeric instead of using a regex pattern.

```
from collections import Counter

>>> text = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.']
>>> filtered = [w for w in text if w.isalnum()]
>>> counts = Counter(filtered)
>>> counts
Counter({'this': 1, 'a': 1, 'is': 1, 'sentence': 1})
```

Advantages:

- Works better with non English languages as `"À".isalnum()` is `True` while bool(nonPunct.match("à")) is `False` (an "à" is not a punctuation mark at least in French).
- Does not need to use the `re` package.

Answer (score 1):

Removing punctuation

```
from string import punctuation   
punctuations = list(punctuation)
punctuations.append("''")
punctuations.append("--")
punctuations.append("``")
from string import punctuation 
text = [word for word in text if word not in punctuations]
```

The average number of character in a word on a text

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize

word_count = Counter(word_tokenize(text))
sum(len(x)* y for x, y in word_count.items()) / len(text)
```