# Python: Shortest way to extract and count elements from an array of String?

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and do know that my question is very simple but I've not found an existed question on SO yet.

I have an array contains string elements. Now I want to extract elements and count the number of appearances of them, them sort in descending order.

For example:

```
['ab' 'ab' 'ac']
```

then the output should be:

```
'ab' 2
'ac' 1
```

Also, it's bad of me that I don't know what is the best way to store my output (in a map, hash... or something like that? Again, I'm not sure)...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Incidentally, this isn't an array,  it's a`list`, or more generally a "sequence".  In python, `array` refers to a specific data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the `Counter` class from the `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['ab', 'ab', 'ac']
counts = Counter(x)
```

`counts` stores the count information for each element; the full list of methods can be found in the [documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html&ei=Ouv1T9vnDoGe2AX0_dGEBw&usg=AFQjCNFTyb_RHzPdorBGavEIR_ekNn_AFA), but probably all you care about is that you can access counts directly by treating `counts` like a hash:

```
counts['ab']
>>> 2
```

Comment: thanks and +1, but then how can I sort by frequency in descending order?

Comment: The `most_common` method will do this. `counts.most_common()` gives a list ordered from most frequent to least frequent of tuples of the form `(elem,count)`. You could iterate over this with e.g. `for elem, count in counts.most_common():`.

Comment: thank you. I will accept this answer. By the way, what is the data type of `counts`?

Comment: It's a `Counter`, a specific class from the `collections` module. You can read about its methods in the documentation I linked. But you can treat it like a `dict` in many contexts (which is the Python version of a map or hash).

Answer (score 1):

There is some library called NLTK.
Link - http://nltk.org/.

EDIT:
I found something better:

You can look here too - [real word count in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677020/real-word-count-in-nltk).

Code example from the above link:

```
    from collections import Counter
    >>> text = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.']
    >>> counts = Counter(filtered)
    >>> counts
    Counter({'this': 1, 'a': 1, 'is': 1, 'sentence': 1})
```

Comment: sincerely I'm working with some NLP stuffs but it would be better if you go more in details... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem, the so called "Word Count" problem.  You would probably want to use a dictionary, python's built in amortized linear lookup type.

Declared like such:

```
dict = {}
```

You can then iterate over your list of tokens with a loop body resembling the following:

```
if token not in dict:
    dict[token] = 1
else
    dict[token] += 1
```

When you're done, you end up with a dictionary containing words as keys and frequencies as values.

The following documentation is relevant: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html